# Ubuntu mate screen tearing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, mate, tearing

Just installed ubuntu mate on my alienware laptop. 
After installing nvidia driver for my gtx 1060 i got screen tearing for everything.. from mozilla to pymol.
I also activated also compiz as windows manager and followed this [guide](http://www.marcosbox.org/2014/07/kde-nvidia-tearing-v-sync-fix.html) but nothing changed. How can i solve this problem? 
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use MATE Tweak to change the Window Manager to "Marco with Compton" or "Compiz", both of those remove screen tearing.

Comment: They didn't solve it.. I using compiz at the moment but i got tearing anyway

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
  Driver      "intel"
  Option      "TripleBuffer" "true"
  Option      "TearFree"     "true"
  Option      "DRI"          "false"
EndSection
```

under `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel_flicker_fix.conf`